# How can I determine what crashed Mobile Safari?

Tags: iphone, crash, mobile-safari

My website crashes on Mobile Safari, but works fine on desktop.

How can I determine why it is crashing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you can do when Safari quits unexpectedly showing your website:

**1. Safari debug console**

Use Safari's debug console. Switch on in your iPhone: Settings->Safari->Advanced->Debug console=on.

For me it says

- 2 HTML errors on Line 6  *(Viewport argument value "device-width" for key "width" not recognized and Viewport argument value "no" for key "user-scalable" not recognized.)*
- 2 HTML tips also n Line 6.

Debug console will be shown next time you check your web page using Safari.

**2. Web Inspector (from iOS 6.0)**

If it is getting more complicated to find out the problem in your webpage use Web Inspector to Debug Mobile Safari. [It is a great tutorial for this.](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari/)

Using IOS Simulator I found that for this particular website all iOS version I have, 5.0, 5.1 and also 6.1, runs the page correctly with crashing the page but on device (iOS 5.0.1) still crashes.

My device runs on iOS 5, so I cannot access Web Inspector, but it is certainly the next step for you to check your site on device and check Web Inspector on your machine.

**3. Use iPhone Configuration Utility's Console**

You can downlod Apple's [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/), then you can access your mobile's Console during Safari test.

Checking your site I see couple of memory warnings which eventually lead to Safari crash.

**4a. Use Xcode's debug facility**

Using Xcode you can also access the device's Console (Window->Organizer->Devices tab->Console).

Your case reported the following on console:

```
Apr 30 10:15:18 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[2489] Builtin profile: MobileSafari (sandbox)   
Apr 30 10:15:38 unknown MobileSafari[2489] <Warning>: Received memory warning. 
Apr 30 10:15:39 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Received memory warning. 
Apr 30 10:15:50 unknown UserEventAgent[12] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created 
Apr 30 10:15:50 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0xb2a4]) Exited: Killed: 9
Apr 30 10:15:50 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilesafari[0xf755]) Exited: Killed: 9
Apr 30 10:15:50 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Application 'Phone' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Apr 30 10:15:50 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Application 'Safari' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Apr 30 10:15:52 unknown ReportCrash[2491] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2013-04-30-101552.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
```

**4b. Use Xcode's debug facility, Instruments**

Another sophisticated way to check what's happening is to use Instruments.

Checking again your site I see many-many low memory warning reported by Safari before it quits. Sadly it doesn't directy help you discovering the web site problem but maybe helps to find Safari open bug reports.

Comment: Interesting.. Line 6 is the viewport meta tag.   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">  This has not been changed.. so confused why it would all of a sudden stop working.   I will turn debug on.. thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you find out something log your solution here to learn from it :)

Comment: I also do not have a debug options.. only a web inspector option but it says I need to connect it to my computer and I don't have a mac to hook it up to.  Also, I see using colons were not correct so I changed to commas.. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> but it is still crashing

Comment: Hey, now it is working on my iPhone Safari without debug errors and crash. The page is not the same as on Desktop but I am able to scroll through. I see some grey area moving when scrolling but it disappears then. Btw the desktop web page is very cool!

Comment: but if I click on a tab inside a page (eg. The "Big" factor tab) it still crashes..

Comment: Ugh... This is going to fry my brain lol.  This site worked perfect this morning on the iphone.  It still crashes for me on load.  And yes, it should look slightly different, mainly the menu on iphone.  Can you do me a favor and run debug again.. since I fixed the semi colons I wonder if it will throw a different error.  And thanks so much for the compliment on the site.  =)

Comment: Codedad, the debug tutorial will not work unless you have a Mac.  I only have a windows box at the moment.  I was able to gather that memory was the issue though thanks someone in the apple forums and via your suggestion.  I have removed several chunks of the larger images and it seemed to fix the issue.  I think all in all, it was just to heavy for the iphone.

Comment: Can't you install OS X on your windows box using virtualization?

Comment: Devices seems to be its own window now under Window->Devices and Simulators, not under Organizer any more

Comment: The "Apple's iPhone Configuration Utility" link is dead, is there a successor?

Answer (score 4):

I had success debugging a crash by doing the following:

1. connect to the phones console using xcode
2. find the crash in the console, in my case is looks like this:

   Sep  2 17:16:21 Edwards-iPhone ReportCrash[7093] : Saved report to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/JetsamEvent-2015-09-02-171621.ips
3. Then go to Diagnostics in settings (settings > privacy > diagnostics & usage data - that's on ios 8.4. It's in a different place on other versions) and find the crash file.

This removes the need to guess at which crash reports the one you experienced.

Comment: In iOS 10+ mobile safari crash reports can be found in: `Settings > Privacy > Analytics > Analytics Data`