# How to identify the cause of a Safari crash on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, mobile-safari, crash-reports

We have a webapp that is very javascript intensive - a lot of activity with custom markers on google maps and potentially a lot of items on the page.

Intermittently and unpredictably, Safari on iOS will give the 'A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded' error.

The majority of the time, this happens after a photo has been input and resized by the broswer - an upload hasn't happened yet.

In researching potential issues, I've found the following links

1. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6707626?tstart=0
2. https://www.quora.com/When-Safari-says-A-problem-occurred-with-this-webpage-so-it-was-reloaded-what-sort-of-problem-has-likely-occurred

The real question is **how do I identify the cause of the crash?** This never occurs on desktop so working out if it's an iOS limitation, a memory issue, a resizing problem or another cause is incredibly difficult.

I've connected an iPhone to a Mac to run the web inspector on the phone but this crash just terminates the whole process without logging any errors so there is no help there either.

Also, there is no reliable way to reproduce the issue - it just happens 'sometimes' with no consistent feature as to what the cause may be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without any context I can tell you to check few things (if it is a web application): check if you are exceeding some number of connections, memory leak (RAM), GPU crash from memory leak or bug in transformations.

Comment: As Wallace suggested you can try sentry.io. It's free for the first month i think. Otherwise i would suggest optimizing execution times and inspect your functions inside the Chrome's performance tab and record a profile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine what crashed Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286041/how-can-i-determine-what-crashed-mobile-safari)

Comment: Does it work on another browser? If yes, what's different between that browser and Safari that is relevant to your project?

Comment: Try inverting your question - e.g why does my code work on desktop?  You have much more scope for profiling and tracing your code on desktop.  You may be unlucky and tripping on a mobile specific bug in the browser, but looking for resource usage and errant behaviour on the desktop might help you identify areas that would stress the constrained resources on mobile.  Just because it appears to 'work' on desktop, doesn't mean you're not leaking resources like a sieve ;-)

Comment: most likely you get this because "out of memory" condition.

Answer (score 1):

You've tried this? :

1. connect your Phone to your Mac and
2. start xcode
3. open `Window->Organizer->Devices tab->Console` and see if there are Errors while reproducing the issue.

Comment: does not work as it autoclosesonce the unhelpful message is shown on the device